# IE9 security mode conflict with @font-face

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, font-face

i was unable to see the css @font-face working in IE9 on any website until i found this option in the "security" tab of the "internet options" : 
- "Activer le mode protégé" (fr_FR) -> "Activate Protected Mode" (en_EN).

while this option is ON, the @font-face property won't work even this URL : 
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/39519/webfontsdemo/index.html

this is a webpage showing all @font-face declarations possible and none works.

Is there a way to bypass this security measure ?
Because it should be activated by most users as there is a popup reminder about "a potential security risk" while not activiting it.

is there anyone experiencing the same ?

thx !

---

**EDIT** : i have set up my own dropbox font-face listing to update after Albert contribution here : 
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13466939/fontfacelisting/index.html

the #IEFIX fix doesn't work, but i found some clues :

1. when I launch the index.html file localy (directly from right-click
   -> *open with internet explorer*) fonts are showing well.
2. when i start IE9 as administrator, the cross domain @font-face
   declaration
       works ! (i've checked all securities options between administrator
       mode and not, and they're the same...

Comment: For the record, protected mode is enabled by default and it does definitely not interfere with `@font-face` here.

Comment: hum... so do you see any reason that should explain that the url given doesn't show the @font-face property when it's on, and it's ok when it's off ?

Answer (score 2):

Follow the menu: Internet Options > Security > When *Enable Protected Mode* is ticked click on the *Custom Level* button. In there look for Downloads > Font Downloads > Tick *Allow*.

Comment: that was a good hint ! but the option is already enabled for all zone in all security levels...

Answer (score 0):

those aren't all the possible @font-face values, you're missing the iefix. check out fontsquirrel http://www.fontspring.com/blog/the-new-bulletproof-font-face-syntax

Comment: i've edited my post with the fontsquirrel syntax. just for the information i can't even get the font on the fontsquirrel website to work

Comment: meh. ie is so nerve wracking. try these options (hope one works!)  http://www.fontspring.com/blog/fixing-ie9-font-face-problems